# How to redirect one URL structure to another url structure?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need help with htaccess redirect rule.
I've thousands of URL with the structure

```
https://www.domainname.com/a/b/c/123456 which needs to be redirected to 
https://www.domainname.com/a/b/c
```

But `https://www.domainname.com/a/b/c/123456/d` should not be redirected at all.

My current rule is using

```bash
Redirect 301 /a/b/c/34624 domainname.com/a/b/c
```

but I have thousands of urls with random number at the end. I need a simple code which can redirect all urls .. I cannot write thousands of line in .htaccess

Is there any rule or a way I can achieve it?

Comment: My current rule is using 
```
Redirect 301 /a/b/c/34624 https://www.domainname.com/a/b/c
```
but I have thousands of urls with random number at the end. I need a simple code which can redirect all urls .. I cannot write thousands of line in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteRule` here that uses a regular expression to match any number after `/a/b/c/` and will discard last part in target.

Have a rule like this in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(a/b/c)/\d+/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Once you have verified that it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Not sure if I can dare to intervene into an answer written by @anubhava ... but ... this does not really answer the actual question.... Citation: "urls with random number at the end". And an explicit exception in the question that supports that phrase. Could it be that you meant `^(a/b/c)/\d+$` ?

Comment: Thanks and very good point @arkascha. Though `.+` would have worked but `\d+` is what OP wanted as per the written requirements, fixed.